# What is this syntax, initializing an interface as it would be an array of classes? (new IItemTransform[0])

Tags: c#, syntax, interface, initialization

*new IItemTransform[0]* is found in System.Web.Optimization.Bundle. I've tried to google for anything regarding this syntax, but with no success due to search queries of too generic words.

```
public virtual Bundle IncludeDirectory(string directoryVirtualPath, string searchPattern, bool searchSubdirectories)
    {
      if (ExceptionUtil.IsPureWildcardSearchPattern(searchPattern))
        throw new ArgumentException(OptimizationResources.InvalidWildcardSearchPattern, "searchPattern");
      PatternType patternType = PatternHelper.GetPatternType(searchPattern);
      Exception exception1 = PatternHelper.ValidatePattern(patternType, searchPattern, "virtualPaths");
      if (exception1 != null)
        throw exception1;
      Exception exception2 = this.Items.IncludeDirectory(directoryVirtualPath, searchPattern, patternType, searchSubdirectories, new IItemTransform[0]);
      if (exception2 != null)
        throw exception2;
      else
        return this;
    }
```

IItemTransform:

```
namespace System.Web.Optimization
{
  public interface IItemTransform
  {
    string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input);
  }
}
```

This feel really unintuitive, does anyone recognize the syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new IItemTransform[0]` is simply creating an array (of size zero) of references to type `IItemTransform`. It's not creating any objects that implement `IItemTransform`.

It's syntactically the same as creating an empty array of strings:

```
string[] foo;
foo = new string[0];
```

It's just an array of `IItemTransform`, not `string`.